# How to determine a Big-O estimate for an algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

This question has been mentioned in the forum but with a different approach.
I need to determine a Big-O estimate for the number of operations of the algorithm below taking into account only additions and multiplications. I have already taken the time to analyzed it and I see that the number of iterations depends on the value of $i$ which doubles at each loop $i = 2^n$. My question is how to determine the function that will provide the number of operations and finally will be used to get the Big-O estimate?

$$
i = 1;\\
t = 0;\\
\text{while} \quad (i <= n) \quad \{t = t + i; i = 2 * i;\}
$$

Comment: The number of iterations depends on the $n$, which I suppose would be your input? Because the iterations stop when $i$ exceeds $n$.

Comment: Isn't the O(n)=log(n) for the given algorithm?

Comment: Yes KittyL, n is an input. For rajashekaroo7, how do you determine that O(n) is log(n)? How to you get to such a conclusion?

Comment: Think about how many loops it will take until i is bigger than n.  i goes from 1 to 2 to 4 to 8 to 16, ... to 2^i.  When is 2^i>n?  Take logs of both sides...

Comment: Thank you TravisJ, that is precisely what I was looking for. I was mistakenly taking the values of 'i' as (2, 4, 8, 16,..., 2^n) and that is not the case because 'n' does not change at all. The increment in the value of 'i' depends on itself. Now the solution is clear to me.